# Can Zenpou hiyaku ukemi be used to replace Zenpou kaiten ukemi?

Tags: aikido, shodokan

I want to know whether it is possible to always use Zenpou hiyaku ukemi instead of Zenpou kaiten ukemi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, zenpou hiyaku ukemi (also known as tobu ukemi or a flip) is nothing but a forward roll (zempo kaiten ukemi) where tori holds uke's hand. They are the same rolls but depending on which technique is performed, one is safer to do than the other.

Secondly, note that when uke performs a flip, they end up close to tori. This is fine when the alternative is a broken wrist but not so good if tori decides to punch uke. A forward roll allows uke to create some distance between themselves and an aggressive tori. Many escapes out of the san-dan section of the goshinho are about uke abandoning what they do and creating distance so they can fight on.

Finally, an ukemi is a safe escape: whatever you do, sometimes it will be a bastardisation of any and all rolls you can do. All that matters is that uke is safe after the escape. If you know and have practised both break falls, your chances of not hurting yourself are increased.